# Kernel Inner Product

Tags: summation

I am trying to follow some lecture notes about computing a kernel from the inner product of two features maps.  I don't understand how this equation:

$<\phi(x),\phi(z)>=1+\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}z_{i} +\sum_{i,j\in\{1....d\}}x_{i}x_{j}z_{i}z_{j} +\sum_{i,j,k\in\{1,...,d\}}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}z_{i}z_{j}z_{k}$

is equal to this:

$=1 + \sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}z_{i}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}z_{i}\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}z_{i}\right)^{3}$

I understand the first two parts of the sum, but not the last two.  Can someone explain how:

$\sum_{i,j,k\in\{1,...,d\}}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}z_{i}z_{j}z_{k} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}z_{i}\right)^{3}$

This equation appears on page 5 of the lecture notes located [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes3.pdf) <sup>[Stanford notes]</sup>.